# Selenium can't find anything after clicking link and updating frame

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am trying to make a script that will mass-apply to jobs on LinkedIn. It is able successfully log in and search for jobs, collect elements that contain the special 'linkedIn-apply' icon, and this is where the problems begin. Once it clicks on one of those, it successfully loads the job posting's page, but after that it CANNOT seem to locate anything.

To add more information, when a job posting is clicked, LinkedIn automatically opens up the posting in a new tab. Is it possible that the driver is still on the main page and doesn't see what is on the other tab?

Entire file:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'byebug'

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"excludeSwitches" => [ "--ignore-certificate-errors" ]})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--test-type]
driver.navigate.to("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin")
# driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element(:name, "session_key").send_keys("someuser") 
driver.find_element(:name, "session_password").send_keys("somepassword") 
driver.find_element(:name, "signin").click()
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
sleep 2
driver.find_element(:link_text, "Jobs").click()
sleep 2
e = driver.find_elements(:class, "in-apply-icon")
if e.empty?
  driver.find_element(:class, "expand-button").click
else
  e.each do |posting|
    posting.click
    sleep 10
    driver.switch_to.frame(0)
    sleep 10
    # THIS is where it gets stuck. It cannot find the 'apply button'. I have tried
 using :id and alas, no luck. I have tried finding other things and no luck.
        driver.find_element(:class, "apply-button").click
        sleep 5
        driver.find_element(:id, "file-browse-input").send_keys(somepath)
        sleep 5
        driver.find_element(:id, "send-application-button").click
        #find and click on apply
        #upload resume
        #submit
        #hit x button/leave
        #hit back button
      end
    end
```

The code towards the bottom is not complete, I am aware of that. I can't even get past clicking the apply button, so it is not important at this time.

Comment: I guess the element you found, were going stale or not accessible as once you apply for one job, the page may refresh.If that is the case, you need to find the apply button after every click. Is it throwing any error.Please share

Comment: @Siva The only console error is the one stating that there is no such element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure if there is a frame , you are switching to the correct frame and then find the element. Switching to frame indexed to Zero takes you to the default frame.

Comment: I actually cant find the frame in the chrome dev tools. I've looked under every parent class of the button element and there is no frame tag anywhere on the document.

Comment: That's a good news. So why are you even trying to switch to a frame through your code driver.switch_to.frame(0)?

Comment: I just checked your scenario in linked in. When you click on a job post, it opens in a new window. you have to switch to this new window and then find the apply button(look for how to switch to a new window in ruby selenium). If I have gathered the same scenario as yours then you problem should be resolved.

Comment: I thought that was the issue, but it seems another issue is more important. When you use `driver.title`, the title of the webpage returned is  'Jobs | home', which is the page displaying ALL the postings. When it clicks on a posting, linkedin opens a new tab automatically, but it seems that selenium still thinks it is on the old tab.

Comment: yes, that's what I also observed. So just switch to new window and  then try to locate the element. Let me know if it works out.